# How to sql:setdatasource where datasource is defined in context.xml and web.xml

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

I am trying to use my defined data source from context.xml and web.xml in my jsp page using sql:setdatasource.

I have been able to directly specify the connection using the following:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bar_db" user="foo"  password="bar123"/>
<sql:query var="result" dataSource="${snapshot}">
SELECT * FROM foo_tb
</sql:query>
```

I would like to get the username, pasword and url out of this file using web.xml and context.xml.

Using something like this:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="conn" dataSource="jdbc/bar_db"
```

Here is what I tried -

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app ...> ...
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Conn</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/bar_db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref></web-app>
```

**Context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/FieldNotifications">
<Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        maxActive="20" 
        maxIdle="8" maxWait="10000" 
        name="jdbc/bar_db" 
        password="bar123" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bar_db" 
        username="foo"/>
</Context>
```

I am using the following tools: Netbeans 8.1, MySQL 5.7, Connector/J

**Update:**
Looking for something other than initParams, but it is my current stop-gap.

I have created context-params & am using the following for now:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbaddress</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bar_db</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbuser</param-name>
    <param-value>foo</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbpassword</param-name>
    <param-value>bar123</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In JSP, I use

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="${initParam['dbaddress']}" user="${initParam['dbuser']}"
   password="${initParam['dbpassword']}"/>
```

Issue remains open:

How to set datasource using context.xml and web.xml? 
By defining a resource or connection pool. Somehow the driver is not accessible.

Comment: Do not use JSTL SQL (nor XML) taglib. They are intented for quick prototyping only and not for production applications. See also Oracle's own Java EE tutorial.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing that JSTL was going against the spirit of MVC separation, but why did they build it then? Did they not think ahead? Nevertheless, I did see an example of including a context defined resource. The current project I am working on is a small 1-2 week effort. And inclusion of the resource was what I was looking for. Thanks for the comment.